# List View Images change position automatically when I tap?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am working on an application in which I have a listview, which is getting populated through an ArrayAdapter. All the things are working fine except an issue which has now become quite irritating.

My list view has a custom layout infalted that contains image and then text. The problem is with image part. When I tap on the list after it is populated the images in the list swap there position. Say, for example image associated to 1st cell goes to 3rd and vice versa and so on. It happens only with Images.  Text remains at its position. I don't know  what the issue is. Please help me out of this severe problem.

Following is my Adapter code:

```
 public class PListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {

Context context;
ArrayList<Product> products;
LayoutInflater vi;
ProgressBar mSpinner;

private ImageView imageView;

public void setItems(ArrayList<Product> items) {
    this.products = items;
}

public ProductListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> productList) {
    super(context, 0, productList);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.context = context;
    this.products = productList;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View v = convertView;
    final Product p = products.get(position);

    if (p != null) {

        if (v == null) {

            vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.sample_singlerow, null);
        }

        imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.product_image);
        TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.product_title);
        TextView summary = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.product_summary);
        TextView price = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.product_price);
        TextView type = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.product_type);
        ImageView pImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.persons);

        if (imageView != null) {
            if (p.getImage() == null) {
                if (p.getImageURL() != null) {

                    new AsyncImageLoader(imageView, p.getImageURL());

                }
            }
        }

        if (title != null) {
            Log.i("Title: ", p.getName());
            title.setText(p.getName());
        }

        if (summary != null) {

            Log.i("Summary: ", p.getDescription());
            summary.setText(p.getDescription().substring(0, 110) + "...");
        }

        if (price != null) {
            Log.i("Price: ", p.getPrice());
            price.setText(p.getPrice());
        }

        if (type != null) {
            Log.i("Type: ", p.getType());
            type.setText(p.getType() + " Person");
        }

        if (pImage != null) {

            try {

                if (p.getType().equals("1")) {

                    pImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.one_person);

                } else if (p.getType().equals("2")) {

                    pImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.two_person);

                }

            } catch (NotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                pImage.setImageDrawable(null);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    return v;
}
```

*Edit:*

public class AsyncImageLoader {
    private final WeakReference imageViewReference;

```
public  AsyncImageLoader(ImageView imageView,String imageUrl) {
    imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    String[] url={imageUrl};
    new BitmapDownloaderTask().execute(url);
}
// static int counter = 0;
// int imageNum = 0;

/**
 * This Interface in used by {@link AsyncImageLoader} to return a response
 * by after loading image
 */

public interface ImageCallback {
    public Drawable temp = null;

    /**
     * Load the Image in imageDrable, Image is loaded form imageUrl
     * 
     * @param imageDrawable
     *            Image in drawable format
     * @param imageUrl
     *            URL of image to be load
     */
    public void imageLoaded(Drawable imageDrawable, String imageUrl);
}

private String LOG_TAG;


class BitmapDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private String url;


    @Override
    // Actual download method, run in the task thread
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
         // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
         return downloadBitmap(params[0]);
    }

    @Override
    // Once the image is downloaded, associates it to the imageView
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            bitmap = null;
        }

        if (imageViewReference != null) {
            ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null && !(bitmap==null)) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
}

Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
    final int IO_BUFFER_SIZE = 4 * 1024;

    // AndroidHttpClient is not allowed to be used from the main thread
    final HttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
    final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
        final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode +
                    " while retrieving bitmap from " + url);
            return null;
        }

        final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                // return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                // Bug on slow connections, fixed in future release.
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FlushedInputStream(inputStream));
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
                entity.consumeContent();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        getRequest.abort();
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "I/O error while retrieving bitmap from " + url, e);
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        getRequest.abort();
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Incorrect URL: " + url);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        getRequest.abort();
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Error while retrieving bitmap from " + url, e);
    } finally {
        if ((client instanceof AndroidHttpClient)) {
            ((AndroidHttpClient) client).close();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
/*
 * An InputStream that skips the exact number of bytes provided, unless it reaches EOF.
 */
static class FlushedInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
    public FlushedInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
        super(inputStream);
    }

    @Override
    public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
        long totalBytesSkipped = 0L;
        while (totalBytesSkipped < n) {
            long bytesSkipped = in.skip(n - totalBytesSkipped);
            if (bytesSkipped == 0L) {
                int b = read();
                if (b < 0) {
                    break;  // we reached EOF
                } else {
                    bytesSkipped = 1; // we read one byte
                }
            }
            totalBytesSkipped += bytesSkipped;
        }
        return totalBytesSkipped;
    }
}
```

}

Please let me know what is the issue. Anxiously waiting for your response.

Comment: I guess some thing wrong in your `AsyncImageLoader()`. What you are using, any queue in your Async task?

Comment: Yes, can you please provide us a code of AsyncImageLoader? I think the problem is somewhere there

Comment: Please see the edit part..I have provided the code for asyncImageloader

Comment: Hi Usama, I am trying to implement similar things. Is it working now? For me its like, i need to swap the players text from Dialog List view to the View. Do you have any working sample? Really appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you have some troubles with Views reusage in Adapter and asynchronous loading.
To optimize performance and memory, instead of inflating views repeatedly, Android tries to "cache" list items in ListView's recycler - that means that the same View (list item) will be used several times, each time for different data item.

If so - let's check what will happen if you'll scroll the existing list: some view will be infated, filled with data and will start to download image for ImageView. In separate thread.

And now what if this View will be reused for another data item, before previous Image was successfully loaded? Currently, a new AsyncTask will be started for this image. And here comes a racing condition, noone knows in which order the result will be returned from the AsyncTask.

So I would recommend you either to store AsyncTask with a View (in Tag, for example), or to make some hashmap.
The main purpose - to determine when bitmap loading is complete - was this image used for another bitmap request or not, if it was - skip image setting, as it's outdated.

This approach will prevent imageViews from displaying wrong image for another item.

Hope it helps, good luck

Answer (score 0):

you need to add bydefault image if the image url is null, Just add else check and add any place holder